# Starburst query failing

Tags: powerbi, trino, starburst

I am trying to load a query in DirectQuery mode from our Starburst Trino database using the starburst connector. I enter all the information correctly, enter my credentials and when I run it, I get the error below:

> Details: "EvaluateNativeQueryUnpermitted failure: the query 'select *
> from hive.interfaces.apa_production_pbi_completion_prod_stats' isn't
> approved for execution."

It does not matter what the query is, or if it has the call to the catalog or not, it always fails.